# How to call http get service in component using output of other http service in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5, angular2-services

I am very new to Angular and have got stuck in how to call services **SYNCHRONOUSLY**..

I am having two http GET services, lets say **ServiceA** and **ServiceB** which are uptill now were called seperately successfully i.e. were independent of each other.

But now  due to requirement change I am forced to call in loop **ServiceB** with parameter value supplied from value returned before by calling **ServiceA** inside a function in component file.

```
for(let i=0;i<3;i++){

    this.ServiceA.methodA().subscribe(result => {

    this.masterID= result.ID;

    console.log('Inside outer service');

     this.ServiceB.methodB(masterID).subscribe(
                    resultInner => {
                      child = resultInner.Text;
                      console.log('Inside Inner service');

                    });

    });

  }
```

I am trying to pass value returned by **ServiceA** stored in variable `masterID` as parameter to inner **ServiceB** and checking calling order by alerts but they are not called in synchronous manner.
Observed behaviour is that before `masterId` value gets populated by successfull response returned by outer **ServiceA**, the inner service i.e. **ServiceB** gets called and paremeter `masterID` is passed empty giving incorrect functionality.

Can somebody please help in making this behave correctly ?

**Behaviour observed in console.log()**

```
Inside Outer service
Inside Outer service
Inside Outer service

Inside Inner service
Inside Inner service
Inside Inner service
```

**Expected Behaviour**

```
Inside Outer service
Inside Inner service
Inside Outer service
Inside Inner service
Inside Outer service
Inside Inner service
```

Comment: if any of the answers answered your questions don't forget to put a check.  Also please consider mine as I believe it is the right approach.  It took me a while to get my head around observables after doing promises for a long time.  It's totally worth mastering.  My Angular code is so much clearer than my angularJs used to be - rxjs is a big reason why.

Answer (score 3):

You should spend some time learning rxjs as it is pretty powerful, but a little hard to wrap your head around at first.   In the example below I do the following.

- Use `from()` to generate an array of items to imitate what you're doing in your example.
- Use `switchMap()` to switch to a new observable `ServiceA.methodA()`
- Use `map()` to alter the stream from the full result to just the master id.
- Use `switchMap` to call a new start a new Observable with the id created in `map()`.
- Use tap to run a side effect from the result of `switchMap()` with `serviceB()` to perform some action with the result.

**Code**

```
from(new Array(3)).pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.ServiceA.methodA()),
    tap(() => console.log('Inside outer service')),
    map(res => res.resultID),
    switchMap(masterID => this.ServiceB.methodB(masterID)),
    tap(() => console.log('Inside inner service')),
    tap(resultInner => {
         // doSomethingWith(resultInner);
         console.log(resultInner.Text);
    })
}).subscribe();
```

I kept the `console.log()` calls and put them in `tap` so you could see the results you want, and remove them from your actual production code when you're ready.

Answer (score 1):

The only error I see is you passing `masterId` without `this.masterId`

```
this.ServiceA.methodA().subscribe(result => {
    this.masterID = result.ID;
    alert('Inside outer service');
    this.ServiceB.methodB(this.masterID).subscribe(
        resultInner => {
            child = resultInner.Text;
            alert('Inside Inner service');
        }
    );
});
```

---

**EDIT** since you have added loop

```
someFunction(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.ServiceA.methodA().subscribe(result => {
            this.masterID= result.ID;
            console.log('Inside outer service');

            this.ServiceB.methodB(masterID).subscribe(
                resultInner => {
                    child = resultInner.Text;
                    console.log('Inside Inner service');
                    return resolve(resultInner); // or whatever
                }
            );
        });
    });
}

async someFunction2(): Promise<any> {
    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        await someFunction();
    }
}
```

Comment: hi vivek, but will this behave synchronously ?? i found that the default  behaviour is async in javascript service calls

Comment: Yes, because you need `masterId` from `ServiceA`. Correct me if I have missed anything to understand.

Comment: the second/innder `subscribe()` will be called only after first/outer `subscribe()` gets resolved.

Comment: It will be nice if you tell, what behavior you are expecting?

Comment: hi vivek, please check edited  in questio  what i am observing and what i expect in console,log